# Complex reports from C# programatically into office Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, report, reporting

First of all I want to say hi to the programming community, what I am looking for is a way to generate a report from my Windows Forms Application in word preferably, this report is basically a list of pre-configured days in a tour creation software I am creating.

I have searched everywhere and I cant seem to find information on how to start creating the report, I have all the information saved into a database, I just need to be able to get this information into word and ordered as it should be ordered.

I just want to be pointed in the right direction so I can research on it even further.

The exact thing I want to create is a word file that I wish I could share here so you can actually see what I mean.

Thank you for all your attention and help if possible.

Comment: Word processors are a huge can of worms and you should avoid having to interface with them at all costs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you in the right direction. Word documents are stored in a format called OpenXml which can be created and manipulated without actually using Word directly. That's good because you don't want to deal with code that actually starts an instance of Word and automates it (Interop.) It sort of works but it's not something I recommend dealing with ever.

OpenXml isn't fun either, but it's better. You can create your document "normally" using Word, save it, and then have your application use it as a template, opening a copy, populating some data, and then saving it.

Here's the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850833.aspx) for OpenXml with Word. I'm not saying it's pretty. It's not. The documentation is lacking. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx) on adding text isn't linked from the previous page, even though many other topics are.

There are some nuget packages like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlPowerTools/) that can help.

I once did a POC that did exactly what you're describing by opening and altering a document used a template using OpenXml. I'll see if I can dig up the code. But this is definitely a good direction to look in *if* Word is an absolute requirement.

This is a long shot, but can you output in HTML? If you can that's an even easier alternative.

Can you use Excel? That's also OpenXml but there's easier-to-use tools like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) that simplify dealing with it, because it's not just the friendliest thing to work with.

Comment: I don't need the output to be precisely word, I could work with an XML file, still I find myself at a dead end trying to get the data from the database to appear in a simpler fashion.

Comment: Scott I am trying to output an HTML because as you said it is actually easier, if you have any advice or documentation for good HTML from winforms it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Scott, I did it all in HTML and it was great, but the client wanted it to be in DOCX format and not HTML. So far I got 90% of the document created. I was wondering if you have ever stored rtf into a sql database, then later retrieve it and paste it into word, I feel like I am finding nothing anywhere on this topic and I just need some help on it now! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, no, I haven't done what you're describing. But typically if you're pasting that means you're manipulating the document through automation. If you can avoid that and work with the underlying document (like with OpenXML) then that's usually better.

Answer (score 1):

An option that I would suggest is Crystal Reports. You can download the Crystal Reports add-in for Visual Studio for free from [here](http://go.sap.com/product/analytics/crystal-visual-studio.html). Crystal Reports is an easy way to perform reporting from various data sources including SQL. There are also a lot of free tutorials online for learning how to use CR. The syntax is a little strange, but it is easy enough to use.

The add-in allows you to create reports for your application and also build applications that can display, print, and export Crystal Reports.

You can export reports to .RTF (Rich Text Format) files. MS Word can open, edit, and convert RTF documents. It does a fairly decent job, but special formatting might take some work. This route is a ton easier than trying to write XML or anything else. I've written several reports designed for export to RTF. My boss runs the report, exports it, then edits it in Word. He loves the reports.

If you are planning on developing a lot of reports, purchasing the full version of Crystal Reports is well worth it. I believe they are on version 2016 currently.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will look into crystal reports right away and start on basic report from the database and work my way from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to deal with automating Word, Microsoft's guide "Automating Applications Using the Office Object Model" Word-specific task content is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78whx7s6(v=vs.80).aspx

A larger example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384

To begin, simply add an assembly reference to your project file for the correct Office Object Library (example: "Microsoft Word ##.0 Object Library").  Note that you must have Office installed to take this approach.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I want a good report, don't care really if it is with word, xml, crystal reports, etc. I mean word is helpful for modifying it somehow but in the end I think what I want is the very best kind of report I can get that allows me to customize it in several ways.